# MVC AccountController with IsAuthenticated false OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have an AccountController with a Login action.

We SignIn the user in our Application Service like that:

```
_signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = userDto.RememberMe }, identity);
```

After that I redirect the user to Home/Index.

In the Home/Index the User.IsAuthenticated is **true**

But before doing this redirection, in the AccountController, even after calling _signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(...) User.IsAuthenticated is **false**.

What are we doing wrong?

Problem is, that I need to unit test the AccountController and want to test if after calling _signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(...), the user is really signed in.

Thank you very much for the help

Daniel

**EDIT:**

After using this code:

```
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

Works fine, but smells weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because authentications based on user's browser cookie. You need a redirect commend to the client to user agent (browser) send the cookie in the new request, then your app could authenticate.

Comment: That was my assumption. But in the AccountController there is still no redirection and I need to check if the user is really authenticated

Comment: Cookie based authentication based on users request and you can not unit test this without receiving new request from the client.

Comment: You could check if Set-cookie response header was sent on the response stream.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link: [ASP.NET Identity AuthenticationManager vs. SignInManager and cookie expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373614/asp-net-identity-authenticationmanager-vs-signinmanager-and-cookie-expiration)

You are using AuthenticationManager, I believe your code is something like this:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
       user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(
       new AuthenticationProperties() { 
          IsPersistent = isPersistent 
       }, identity);
}
```

You can use `SignInManager`. Its `PasswordSignInAsync` method returns a SingInStatus result. In that case, your code should be something like this:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
```

To see how to use it, make sure you have the latest version of visual studio 2013 and create a new asp.net web application project, using "Individual User Accounts" as "Authentication Type"

Comment: This looks good, I'll give it a try. We don't use Async though