# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated always false after PasswordSignInAsync gives success

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, forms-authentication, identity

I've got a standard MVC project, with the UserManager and SignInManager objects and an AccountController, with the pre-created login and register type functionality.

I can register new users to my AspNetUsers table, but when I login I call:-

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

The data is coming through from the form correctly, and the result is Success, which I expected.

I then tried the following redirects:-

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
    //return RedirectToLocal("/admin/");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
```

but on any page, after this successful login, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false, and User.Identity.Name is an empty string.

What am I doing wrong? I've done another project in the same way with the same setup in the past and I've had zero problems.

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <!--<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login/" timeout="1000" />
    </authentication>-->
    <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
<modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong? It's causing major issues now.

Cheers!

Comment: Have you configured `CookieAuthenticationOptions` during start up?

Comment: what version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: .NET 4.5. I believe we fixed it, with another developer. Looks like a clash with the server authentication.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642630/user-identity-isauthenticated-is-false-after-successful-login)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if you have a `Startup.Auth.cs` file in your `App_Start` folder in the project.

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {            
        // This uses cookie to store information for the signed in user
        var authOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,                
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7),
        };
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(authOptions);
    }
}
```

and is called from the `Startup` class

```
public partial class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        // Surface Identity provider
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        //..other start up code
    }
}
```

Depending on the version of asp.net and identity you are using, you should take a look at this

[ASP.NET Identity AuthenticationManager vs. SignInManager and cookie expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26379141/5233410)

Comment: Thanks for this, will bookmark it. We already had this code in the project, but it looks like it was something on the server causing a clash authentication.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the web.config, comment following lines

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      -->
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```